# Rails 4 external redirection and sessions issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redirect, cookies

I am trying to build a website in Rails 4 to track users redirects and site element views.

I decided to use session ids which I believe are quite unique in the short term but I'm having a strange issue.

Example procedure:

1. user follows a redirect, the system stores this action with a Session ID, let's say `xxx`
2. user reaches destination page, which contains a tracker, the system stores this action with ANOTHER Session ID, `yyy`
3. user reaches another page which also contains a tracker, the system stores this action with Session ID `yyy`

After the second action is stored, the session ID stays the same `yyy` for every request after that, but I need to have the same session ID every time.

In session I also store a SecureRandom.hex generated code, which also changes from the first to the second request (which is not a surprise, since the session ID changes).

I also tried using a cookie, same result.

Please notice that these redirects are external, but all the requests are then made to the same domain (exactly the same, without www and in https).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

### Update

this is the source code responsible for managing redirects:

```
before_action :load_redirect, :only => [:http_redirect]

def http_redirect
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Redirect has been disabled') unless @redir.enabled

  ua = UserAction.create(
    :session_id => session.id,
    :user_agent => request.user_agent,
    :trackable => @redir,
    :ip_address => request.remote_ip,
    :referer => request.referer
  )
  redirect_to @redir.destination_url
end

private
  def load_redirect
    @redir = Redirect.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Since you are using an iframe (per comment discussion below) for tracking code, the issue is likely that on the external site cookies are not being passed from parent page to the iframe because the iframes origin (domain) is different from the parent page.

**OLD ANSWER:
(Still could be helpful for others debugging similar issues)**

Source code would help. Without that, here are a few things to try:

1. Try **disabling CSRF protection** for the external tracking link action (I'm assuming it POSTs or PUTs data from an external source). CSRF protection could be creating a new or null session for those requests. Put this in the controller that contains the action accepting data from the external source:

   ```
   protect_from_forgery :except => [:your_action]
   ```
2. The redirect (especially if it's a 301) **could be cached in the browser** you are using, hence having a different cookie and session than the request your tracking code makes. The stale cookie would be part of the cached redirect.

   Try putting cache control headers on your controller action that does the redirect.

   ```
   response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
   response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
   response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
   ```
3. Your browser may not support setting cookies on a redirect, or possibly third-party cookies. Try in a different modern browser?
4. There could be a bug in your code. If these solutions don't work, maybe post it?

Comment: Added the source code responsible for the redirect in the OP. Added response headers to the code, will let you know if it works asap.

Comment: Since the site is not available to users, forgery is already disabled sitewide. I know it's not a great idea but it was the first thing I tried. Added response headers but doesn't seem to work. Redirect is 302 (default for rails redirect_to). Any more idea? Anything from my code?

Comment: I assume you tried different browsers, right? It looks to me so much like a CSRF issue the more I think about it -- how did you disable CSRF (want to double-check?). Other than that, I'd say post your javascript tracker code

Comment: If you are using ajax/javascript for the tracking code try setting `withCredentials`

Comment: Yes, I tried several browsers. Tracker code is made through an iframe tag which links to a action in another controller. It outputs only a verification string. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Yes, that is an issue :) If the parent page is a different domain from the iframe, I am pretty sure cookies won't be passed from parent to iframe

Comment: However I need to set cookies INSIDE iframe page, I'm not trying to set cookies in the parent page. Is that possible? In fact, cookies inside iframes seem consistent over time, while the issue seems to be in the redirects. I also tried redirecting via JS, no luck.

Comment: The user's browser has your session cookie (from your domain) and they load an external page (let's call it the parent page) on an external domain. The child iframe (your iframe, nested in the parent page) won't be passed any cookies from the user's browser because the iframe domain is different from the parent page (even if the cookie domain matches!). I am pretty sure.